# How to traverse tuple in rust?

Tags: rust

How to traverse this tuple in rust below?

```
fn main() {
   let tuple = ((353,1,0),(353,2,1676),(265,1,0,"Fire Note"),(1412,1,0,"Fire Note"));
}
```

I tried to create a struct, but I don't know what to do next.

```
    struct Note {
        start_time:u64,
        key:u64,
        length:u64,
        note_type:String,
    }
```

Update:
If tuple can not be traversed, what value type should I use?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want? Do you want all nested values of the tuple? What have you tried?

Comment: @Smitop yes, I need to read every nested value.

Comment: @zwl1619 Are you aware that tuples have a fixed length? This would almost certainly be done better with a slice or `Vec` of `Note`s, rather than using fixed-length tuples here.

Comment: @Smitop It has  different value types.

Comment: do you want `note_type: Option<String>,` ?

Comment: @Stargateur `note_type:String` is not right, is it?

Comment: If it has different types, how can you iterate over it in the first place? If you could do `for x in tuple {...}` then what could you reasonably do with `x` in the `...`, since you don't know which type it is?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this, but it's a really bad idea. Tuples have fixed length and data at compile time, and this is almost certainly not what you want to do.

But if you really think this is a good idea, you can use a macro to simplify the traversing. Since the length and values of tuples are fixed at compile time, this can hardcode some information about each tuple element when invoking the macro.

```
macro_rules! note {
    (unnamed $idx:tt) => {
        Note {
            start_time: tunple.$idx.0,
            key: tunple.$idx.1,
            length: tunple.$idx.2,
            note_type: String::new(), // default to empty string if none provided
        }
    };
    (named $idx:tt) => {
        Note {
            start_time: tunple.$idx.0,
            key: tunple.$idx.1,
            length: tunple.$idx.2,
            note_type: tunple.$idx.3.to_string(),
        }
    };
}
let parsed = (
    note!(unnamed 0),
    note!(unnamed 1),
    note!(named 2),
    note!(named 3),
);
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c7d20a391c900695ec689d7a2abf2b6)